# QuickCheck values equal

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I have a QuickCheck property that looks like this:

```
prop42 :: Foo -> Bool
prop42 foo = fn1 foo == fn2 foo
```

If this property fails, it will print out what `foo` was. But I'd really like to know what `fn1` and `fn2` returned. And if `foo` is large, it's kinda non-trivial to generate this information by hand. (I.e., sit there and manually type in the huge wedge of text printed to the Windows console window.)

It's common for testing frameworks to have a thing that compares for equality, and prints out both values if equality didn't hold. But I can't seem to find such a function for QuickCheck...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at combinators from [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.6/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#g:15). For example, `printTestCase` allows to add an arbitrary string to the output of failing cases. A quick example:

```hs
prop x = let f = sin x
    in printTestCase ("Should be at least " ++ show f) $ x >= sin x
```

```
$> quickCheck prop
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 2 tests and 1 shrink): 
-1.0
Should be at least -0.8414709848078965
```

Comment: This works but deprecated. Instead, using `===` may be enough; it [prints both sides when comparison fails](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.7.3/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Property.html#v:-61--61--61-).

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer from Yuuri, this is what I went with:

```
(?==?) :: (Eq x, Show x) => x -> x -> Property
x ?==? y =
  printTestCase ("Left:  " ++ show x) $
  printTestCase ("Right: " ++ show y) $
  x == y
```

Now I can write things like

```
prop42 :: Foo -> Prop
prop42 foo = fn1 foo ?==? fn2 foo
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one could do the following, assuming that `fn1` and `gn2` return `Bar`:

```
newtype Bar1 = B1 Bar deriving Show
newtype Bar2 = B2 Bar deriving Show
instance Arbitrary Bar1 where
   arbitrary = arbitrary >>= return . B1 . fn1
instance Arbitrary Bar2 where
   arbitrary = arbitrary >>= return . B2 . fn2

prop_xx = forAll arbitrary $ \(B1 b1) ->
             forAll arbitrary $ \(B2 b2) ->
                b1 == b2
```

Comment: Wow. Ingenious. Fortunately, it's not required.

Comment: @kosmikus Thanks for editing. I think we could also just write `prop_xx (B1 b1) (B2 b2) = b1 == b2` but wasn't sure at that moment.